# Is Tizen with angularJs works in web apps

Tags: angularjs, mobile-website, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am trying to build a web app in tizen environment, I found that tizen is using jQuery mobile for ui design.
I want to know that can i use tizen with angularJs for my web app (App should run in tizen emulator). 
If yes, can anyone have good resource or tutorial about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use, Down the line its a web application, a library which works on latest browsers can be used in tizen OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever JS library you want on Tizen. You can even use something else than the recommended jQuery Mobile UI library for the UI part. I personally prefer to use Enyo.js for UI, but AngularJS will also do the job.